# LaunchScreen.Storyboard is not displayed when launching the app

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.ios

I launched the app on the iOS Simulator and on a real device. Neither of them showed the LaunchScreen.
I added the .storyboard file to info.plist and ticked the "use as launch screen" box in Xcode.
I don't see the right background color nor the image I've added to resources and used in an ImageView.
I've searched for this question but I couldn't find other people with the same problem as me.
Thanks in advance for the answers.

### Edit:

As requested, here the info.plist:

[image]

and the XCode storyboard settings:

[image]

Comment: Code from `.plist` file and a screenshot from Storyboard Builder would help

Comment: check your `AppDelegate.swift` -> `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` -> perhaps it's done manually...
Maybe the launch time is that short that you don't see it?

Comment: @charlyatwork didFinishLaunchingWithOptions returns true in my AppDelegate.cs. Is this whats is supposed to be?
The launch time should be long enough. I see a black screen while app is loading.

Comment: I would suggest you to delete the launch screen completely and clean/rebuild your project. Then add a new launch screen there and try again.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT okay I'll try it.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT At first I tested it in a different project with only text on the LaunchScreen and it worked. But as I tried to do it in the main project, where my LaunchScreen has an ImageView it didn't work. My Problem was that the ImageView was in assets and couldnt load somehow. When I put it into resources everything worked fine.

Comment: Can you have a try with another image to check whether the specific image caused the problem?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Yep I tried it with other images in assets but it wasn't just this one. All of the images based in assets didn't work. And all images in my resources did work. I don't know why. Maybe images in assets need more time to load and the loading time was bigger than the launch time of my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer:

The image in my ImageView was in assets.xcassets. Somehow it couldn't load there and disabled my entire LaunchScreen. I had to put it in resources to make it work. And as my ImageView was able to load, I could see the whole LaunchScreen, instead of just a black screen.